# reduction of order with tricky first solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I must be doing something wrong. Given the ODE $2x^2 y''-6xy'+10y=0$ and the solution $x^2cos(lnx)$ use reduction of order to find a second solution.

So let $y=vy_1=vx^2cos(lnx)$. Now I need to calculate $(vx^2cos(lnx))''$ which is quite ugly. Are there any better ways?

Comment: @Amzoti sorry yes $x^2$ and yes it is required to use reduction of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this generally.
We start with a linear ODE, $y^{\prime\prime} + p(x)y^\prime + q(x)y=0$ and $y_1$ is a solution, and we let $y_2=v(x)y_1$. Then, it's derivatives are given by
$$y_2^\prime=v^\prime y_1 +vy_1^\prime$$
$$y_2^{\prime\prime}=v^{\prime\prime}y_1 + 2v^\prime y_1^\prime + vy_1^{\prime\prime}$$
Plugging this in to the original ODE gives us
$$v^{\prime\prime}y_1+2v^\prime y_1^\prime + vy_1^{\prime\prime} +p(x)v^\prime y_1 +p(x)vy_1^\prime +q(x)vy_1=0$$
Now collect everything with a $v$:
$$v^{\prime\prime}y_1+2v^\prime y_1^\prime +p(x)v^\prime y_1 +v(y_1^{\prime\prime}+p(x)y_1^\prime +q(x)y_1)=0$$
Now, since $y_1$ is a solution of the equation, that means that entire $v$ term just becomes zero. And so we're left with
$$v^{\prime\prime}y_1+(2y_1^\prime+p(x)y_1)v^\prime=0$$

Then you can just use that equation, which only requires calculating the first derivative of your first solution instead of that ugly thing.  On a side note, if you do choose to do it this way, make sure that your original equation is in the right form, i.e. $y^{\prime\prime}$ is on its own.